# Is GTA V Free with Xbox Live Gold on Xbox One S?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one, xbox-network

I used to play a lot of Xbox with my stepbrothers, who own Xbox Live Gold. I don't live with my dad anymore, so I decided to get my own Xbox One S and - due to my stepbrothers and I being in a family - I am able to get Gold from them.

I'm especially really excited to play GTA V, but I can't seem to find a crucial bit of info: can I play GTA V on an Xbox One S, and if so, would I be able to get it for FREE with Xbox Live Gold?

**Note:** I'm not trying to sell anything, I'm just wanting to know if I buy an Xbox One S, will I be able to play GTA V on it, and if it is free with Gold.

Answer (score 3):

GTA: V is an Xbox One game, and therefore, is able to be played on an Xbox One S.

Unfortunately, GTA: V is not available through Xbox Live Gold. It is only available with 'Game Pass', offered as a part of Xbox Live *Ultimate*, a more expensive Xbox Live subscription tier:

[image: GTA V On Xbox Live Game Pass]

- [GTA V on Xbox Live](https://www.xbox.com/en-au/games/gta-v)
- [Xbox Game Pass](https://www.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-game-pass/games)

Here's some [further reading](https://us.cnn.com/2021/01/25/cnn-underscored/xbox-live-gold-vs-game-pass-ultimate) on the comparison between Ultimate and Gold.